# Spring boot datasource specific properties for embedded jetty server

Tags: spring-boot

I have spring boot application and it's basically a gradle project, so, I have below dependency added in my gradle file:

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.1.RELEASE
```

Application gets deployed in embedded jetty server. I have following set of properties in application.properties for db connection polling:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name
spring.datasource.max-active
spring.datasource.max-idle
spring.datasource.min-idle
spring.datasource.validation-query
spring.datasource.name
```

I was referring to below two links:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Configuration-Changelog

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.5-Configuration-Changelog

I came to know that some of the datasource properties which used in application.properties file in my application are removed starting sprint boot version 1.4 but issue they haven't mentioned what are the new properties to use. Like for tomcat server they have provided all set of properties but not for jetty server. I am facing some db related errors like 'too many connections' after my application run for sometime, my assumption is that datasource props I am currently using are not correct and should be replaced with correct values, but unfortunately I am unable to find correct property names.

Answer (score 0):

Jetty doesn't have its own Pooling DataSource implementation. You can include HikariCP in your project and customise using the `spring.datasource.hikari.*` properties. With each property matching the bean properties that can be set on Hikari's datasource implementation.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have added hikari props, do you have any idea how I can ensure if these new properties are really read and connection pool is created?